# Git - added wrong folder source

Tags: git

So I have a git stash master branch(?) and I CD'd into the wrong folder and pushed all the contents to the master.

How do I get rid of everything and start again, and push the correct folder contents?

```
git init
Initialized empty Git repository in D:/apps/myapp_old/.git/
git add --all
git commit -m "Initial commit"
git remote add origin https://url/my_app.
git push -u origin master
```

I tried this:

```
$ git rm -r *
fatal: pathspec 'tmp' did not match any files
```

Comment: I'm confused. You initialized a new git repo and committed the wrong source folder? If that's the case, you can just remove the `.git` folder to wipe out the repo.

Comment: so just delete it from my local folder? But all the files will still be in my github (well technically stash)

Comment: Still confused. You did a `git init`. That initializes a new repo in a local directory. No github (or stash) involved there.

Comment: edited my question with more detail

Comment: Yikes. If you're working with a remote, you should really use `git clone` to create a local version, not init a new one and add a remote.

Comment: it was a brand new remote with nothing in it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do I get rid of everything and start again, and push the correct folder contents?

If you just want to remove the current content of the repository and start all over again:

Simply delete the `.git` folder and add any content you want

```
  rm -rf .git 
  git init 
  git add .
  git commit -m "message"
```

---

#### How to remove content already in the remote repo?

```
# remove any content from the repo
git rm --cached <any files you want to remove"

# update the removed files
git add . -A 

# commit the file you have deleted
git commit -m "..."

# push changes
git push origin <branch>
```

***`NOTE:`***
The content will be in the repository and in the next commits it will be removed

---

---

#### How to remove content from the repository and all its history

You can user interactive rebase of git filter-branch

In order to edit and change the history (`rebase`) follow those steps:

```
// X is the number of commits you wish to squash
git rebase -i HEAD~X
```

Once you squash your commits - choose the `e` for edit, when the process stops remove the desired file and then continue and commit your changes.

[image]

Once you have completed the `rebase` push the changes with `git push -f`

***`NOTE:`***
Rebase is a destructive and should only be done on branches which no one else has checkout or their work will be lost.

---

## More Options:

[How to change the content of the repo - reverting or undoing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34519665/how-to-move-head-back-to-a-previous-location/34519716#34519716)

Comment: so I just cd to my new folder and push from there?

Comment: yep. `rm -rf .` , `git init`, `git add .`, `git commit -m "message"` and that it

Comment: but what about the files that already exist which have been pushed up to stash?

Comment: Ha, got you now, updating the answer accordingly.

Comment: $ git rm --cached -r *
fatal: pathspec 'tmp' did not match any files

Comment: remove the -r, still updating my answer, will take few more minutes to complete

Comment: Since you had a new repository you can simply delete the remote repo on the server, follow the above steps in the comment and push again.

Comment: Ok I trust you, great help

Comment: It you have any problems add comments and ill help you to resolve it.

Answer (score 1):

You're going to have to remove all of the source files that you accidentally added in your local branch, recommit, and re-push to the remote.